# Creating an XML document to be used by multiple programs C#

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, xpath

Quick rundown of what I am trying to do... I have a form that I created [image] What this will do is when the user clicks the `Add` button it will bring up a file browser dialog and let the user select a file.

Upon selection the file will be added to an XML document and the report list.

The remove button I think is self explanatory.

I need this file to have the ability to be read by another program that I created so it can get the proper information accordingly.

I was thinking of using a Data Set, but decided against that because I need to have a fixed location of the xml file, and if I have a Data Set I don't know where the users computer will place the source for the data set. That is why I figured I would skip the data set and just make the XML file manually.

Only thing is it is pretty error-ridden, I fix one error, a new one pops up. The error that I am currently getting happens in the `addButton` method and says that I cannot access the XML file because it is already being used by another process. Tried fixing this by making sure the file was closed prior to access, but still didn't do the trick.

I use a regular `XmlDocument` to read and edit items in the list, and then I use `XPath` to add a completely new item. Below is the complete code and XML format, but I will say right now that I am not very happy with it, because it is very inconsistent. So I guess my main question is what would be the proper way to do this?

### C# Code

```
public partial class selectPOSReports : Form
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

        public selectPOSReports()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            if (!File.Exists(@"C:\Users\Public\MEC\posReportList.xml"))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\Users\Public\MEC");
                doc.LoadXml("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><Reports count=\"0\"></Reports>");
                doc.Save(@"C:\Users\Public\MEC\posReportList.xml");

            }
            else
            {
                doc.Load(@"C:\Users\Public\MEC\posReportList.xml");
            }

            XmlNodeList excelReportList = doc.SelectNodes("//Workbook");

            foreach (XmlNode excelReport in excelReportList)
            {
                reportList.Items.Add(excelReport.InnerText);
            }
        }

        private void addButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int newIndex = 0;
            if ( selectReportDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK ) {
                doc.Save(@"C:\Users\Public\MEC\posReportList.xml");
                string fileName = selectReportDialog.FileName;
                string filePath = Path.GetPathRoot(fileName);
                XDocument xd = XDocument.Load(XmlReader.Create(@"C:\Users\Public\MEC\posReportList.xml"));
                xd.Element("Reports").Add(
                    new XElement("Report", new XAttribute("id", newIndex),
                    new XElement("Workbook", fileName),
                    new XElement("Filepath", filePath)));
                xd.Save(@"C:\Users\Public\MEC\posReportList.xml");
                reportList.Items.Add(fileName);
            }
        }

        private void removeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to remove " + reportList.SelectedItems.ToString() + " from the list?",
                            "Remove Excel Report",
                            MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
                            MessageBoxIcon.Warning);

            if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                int index = reportList.SelectedIndex;
                string sindex = index.ToString();
                XmlNode deleteNode = doc.GetElementById(sindex);
                deleteNode.ParentNode.RemoveChild(deleteNode);
                doc.Save("posReportList.xml");
                reportList.Items.RemoveAt(index);
            }
        }
    }
```

### XML Layout

```
<Reports count="1"><!--Count will be updated as items are added-->
    <Report id="1">
        <Workbook>SomeBook.xlsx</Workbook>
        <Filepath>C:/SomePath</FilePath>
    </Report>
</Reports>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You have two save commands on your addbutton click event

```
doc.Save(@"C:\Users\Public\MEC\posReportList.xml");
```

and

```
xd.Save(@"C:\Users\Public\MEC\posReportList.xml");
```

Guessing you only need the second one and the first was some sort of remnant of refactoring effort?

Comment: they are 2 different objects. I added the `doc.save` because I was getting a file in use error when doing `xd.save` so I thought maybe that was because I had it opened already as an `XmlDocument`. But I still get an error.

Comment: Try this instead then
XDocument xd = XDocument.Load(@"posReportList.xml");

Still, don't understand why you are saving it twice, they might be different objects by the backing store is the same, i.e posReportList.xml

Comment: That actually worked, and `doc.save` is not needed. Well, it wasn't needed at all I was just trying to get rid of some errors. Trying to work out some of the kinks, but the remove isn't working now... give me a couple of minutes to figure out whether it is an error in logic or just syntax

Comment: On the remove, you are saving to @"posReportList.xml", whereas everywhere else you are saving to c:\users\...\ that is likely to be an issue

Comment: That is probably going to be the next error :P right now the error occurs when trying to remove the child (The line before) but I suspect it's because I need to make a few changes to how the elements are saved to the xml file.

Comment: have you checked that deleteNode is not null?

Comment: I have not, but it obviously is null. I just don't know why. That means that `doc.GetElementById(sindex)` is not getting the element

Comment: Looks like you have to define the id type, see this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.getelementbyid.aspx)